# block scheme for c# method

Tags: c#, diagram

Hello all please help me. I have a small method for my student project to search data inside a DatagridView.

```
private void searchbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string searchValue = textBox1.Text;
            if (searchValue != "")
            {
                productsDataGridView.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
                //search 
                try
                {
                    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in productsDataGridView.Rows)
                    {
                        if (row.Cells[1].Value.ToString().Equals(searchValue))
                        {
                            row.Selected = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception exc)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Нічого не знайдено");
                }
            }
            //search by category
            if(comboBox1.SelectedValue!=null)
            {
                try
                {
                    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in productsDataGridView.Rows)
                    {
                        if (row.Cells[5].Value.Equals(comboBox1.SelectedValue))
                        {
                            row.Selected = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception exc)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Нічого не знайдено");
                }
            }
        //end
    }
```

Only problem for me is that I have to draw a block scheme for this method. Is there any tool that I can use to generate the scheme from this source code or any tool that is accessible with screen reading software to accomplish this task?

Comment: @Bogdan Being unfamiliar with tools of that type, I'd recommend to contact your professor/teacher and ask them how you are supposed to do this. Maybe a fellow student can draw it by your verbal instructions or even they will help you?

Comment: I have not used them, but Microsoft has diagram related software called Visio and looks like it has some accessibility support. I do not know how deep is that support, maybe it is worth checking. Check this link [Visio - Accessibility support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/accessibility-support-for-visio-7ac46c50-02c2-44ab-aa1c-711482099276)

Comment: Mybe better suited for https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/